# for loop in Sql procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005

i want to implement for loop to fetch the data from select statement.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why loop when SQL Server is optimized for set based operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asking abour cursors, but cursors are evil, because they have a bad performance. Mosts of times there is a better aproach to solve the problem without using it. But if you still want to do it, here is a very simple snippet of code.

```
DECLARE @somevariable VARIABLE_TYPE_HERE
DECLARE @sampleCursor CURSOR
SET @sampleCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT somefield... from bla bla bla...
OPEN @sampleCursor 
FETCH NEXT
FROM @sampleCursor INTO @somevariable 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @somevariable 
FETCH NEXT
FROM @sampleCursor INTO @somevariable 
END
CLOSE @sampleCursor 
DEALLOCATE @sampleCursor
```